# Internet Explorer unwanted artifact on images when using javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, photos, artifacts

We're having the following weird (well...) behavior in all versions of Internet Explorer browsers when using javascript slideshows.

You can see what I mean here http://www.tospirto.net/index.php?ID=photo_gallery&Rec_ID=481

In the last 3 images there are white lines and artifacts created by the browser.
This is true as I said for all versions of Internet Explorer.

Have you seen this before??
Do you ave any idea what is causing this???

Thank you

Comment: can you add screenshot , as i dont have ie?

Comment: are the images shown at 100%, or are they resized on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found what was wrong after some searching.
The effect is called swiss army image artifacts and you can find more about it here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=34462

Another great bug from explorers :)

The solution is on the referenced article which is to remove absolute blacks using the levels tool on the photoshop for example. Did a batch change using actions in photoshop for all pictures and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the artifacts - strange! This is a known issue in IE's JPEG rendering algorithm. If you enlarge the pictures in Photoshop, you will see that the artifacts are restricted within encoding blocks. (Pardon me, but I assume you know roughly how JPEG is encoded.)

Try encoding the images with a different quality, or even in a different format (like PNG, even though that would give you larger files). You can find other thoughs on how to solve this here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie-dead-pixels-when-fading-images

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the `alpha` filter, which is how transparent fades are implemented in IE (before version 9, which finally supports proper CSS `opacity`). When used directly on an image, any pixel with the RGB values 2,5,10 (aka `#02050A`) is treated as transparent.

This is how 1-bit transparency from eg. GIF is implemented in the `alpha` filter. Evidently Microsoft think this particular colour is so seldom used no-one will notice. Oops.

Avoid the bug by putting the `alpha` filter (or fade script that uses it) on a container `<div>` instead of on the image itself.

Alternatively, you can use an `AlphaImageLoader` filter (same hack as for transparent PNG loading on IE6) to load the image, or just get rid of the `alpha` filter when you're not in the middle of a fade (you still see the bug during fade but at least it doesn't appear at 100%).